# Expression with commas in assert

Tags: python, assert

What does comma do in this line of Python code? Is it correct?

```
assert (response_data['data']['name'] == 'pl1', response_data['data']['status'] == 'active', response_data['data']['version'] == 1)
```

Comment: It probably does not do what the author thinks. It creates a tuple, which may be `(False, False, False)`, and still evaluate as a truthy value…

Comment: That assertion is not correct. You're asserting on the truthiness of a non-empty tuple.

Answer (score 1):

> What does comma do in this line of Python code?

```
(response_data['data']['name'] == 'pl1', response_data['data']['status'] == 'active', response_data['data']['version'] == 1)
```

is 3-tuple

> Is it correct?

[`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assert_stmt) does consider truth-iness of provided expression, every non-emtpy `tuple` is `True`, therefore you will never get `AssertionError` due to this line.

You might use `all` if you want `AssertionError` if one or more conditions does not hold

```
assert all((response_data['data']['name'] == 'pl1', response_data['data']['status'] == 'active', response_data['data']['version'] == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it's not what you want to achieve. In such case `assert` evaluates the whole expression in the parentheses, which is just a tuple: `(bool, bool, bool)`. And since this tuple is not empty (it has three elements), it will be always evaluated to `True`. Just as not empty string or not empty list.

If you want to check all these conditions, do it separately (or maybe by using `all()`).